# Distance between two planes

Tags: geometry

So I have two planes

$$2x + 3y - z = 0 \tag{1}$$

$$x - 4y + 2z = -5 \tag{2}$$

However it seems these two planes are perpendicular to each other, since the coefficients (and the distance would then be zero).

Here's the problem:
$$\frac 21=\frac3{-4}=\frac{-1}2$$
are inequal to each other so what am I missing here?

Comment: $(-1,0,-2)$ is an element of both of them. So the distance is indeed $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly these planes intersect, because their normal vectors are not linearly independent; therefore, the distance between them is zero.

The dot product of their normal vectors are
$$(2,3,-1)\cdot(1,-4,2)=2-12-2\neq0$$
hence they are not perpendicular.

Comment: "because their normal vectors are not linearly independent" >> because their normal vectors are not colinear.